# 2005 Ford Explorer XLS Sport, Random Hesitations and Die Offs

Tags: troubleshooting, fuel-system

I have a 2005 Ford Explorer XLS Sport edition with just under 80,000 miles on it. It does have a warranty on it via my financing company however it's a bit out of pocket for it so I'm hoping that with my handy skills that I may be able to fix this problem myself.

The vehicle, at random times, will start to sputter, jump, and then eventually as the RPMs go too low, die off. It doesn't do it in the mornings, it doesn't do it after a long trip. Just whenever it feels like it, where ever.

It's done it most prominently at intersections, but it's also done it in a parking lot after being parked for five minutes and starting back up.

I've seen mention that it may be my fuel filter, fuel pump, inertia sensor switch, hoses, etc. but I'm just not sure where to start looking for this issue.

A gas treatment does seem to help, however that in itself may just be a placebo. I use recently SeaFoam, and more recently a 3000 mile fuel cleaning system that seems to help.

It does seem to have the issue when the fuel tank goes low, however it doesn't do it all the time. Sometimes when it gets filled up it may do it, other times it wont, likewise when it's getting low. When the issue does arise where the vehicle starts to keel over, if it dies by itself, I get a "Low Oil Pressure" message.

But we usually try our best to stop it beforehand to try to save the catalytic converters.

Answer (score 1):

Well after having no luck in trying to resolve the issue myself, we finally took the vehicle in. The technician was able to only get one code after trying to get it to reproduce the issue. Fuel Pressure Sensor fault. We had it replaced, a week latter now and still running strong. The technicians explanation was that the fuel pressure sensor pump starts to fail off either due to arcing, or just pure bad connections sending erroneous data to the computer. The computer would try to run the fuel pump harder to get better pressure in result causing it to turn off.

Issue number one down of my 2005 Explorer, now down to the easy-to-fix Air handling issue